# drawable fit <bitmap> width to the view while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-drawable

Let's say I have a horizontally long image, "grass". Now, I want to use it as a background image for views, but I want to dock it to the bottom. After searching the web, I discovered that I need to wrap the image as a drawable like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/grass"
    android:gravity="bottom|left" />
```

The problem is that the image is clipped to the right. So I have tried `bottom|left|right` but then the aspect ratio was not kept. Can I make the image fit horizontally, but keep the aspect ratio by automatically scaling it vertically? Or is this not possible with drawables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what your searching for is centerInside ScaleType . please remove the ScaleType from the ImageView and try this :

```
 public static synchronized Bitmap centerInside(Bitmap bitmap,int width,int height){
    if(bitmap.getWidth() == bitmap.getHeight()){
        Log.i("crop","already matched");
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    }
    //int size = width > height ? width : height;

    float scale = ImageUtils.calculateImageSampleSize(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),width,height);
    width = (int) ((float)bitmap.getWidth() / scale);
    height = (int) ((float)bitmap.getHeight() / scale);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);

    if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()){

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                bitmap.getWidth()/2 - bitmap.getHeight()/2,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight(),
                bitmap.getHeight()
        );

    }else{

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                bitmap.getHeight()/2 - bitmap.getWidth()/2,
                bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getWidth()
        );
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot achieve this with XML only. If you don't want to have to draw the bitmap programmatically, you wrap an ImageView in a RelativeLayout and set the ImageView's [scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType) property:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/grass"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand Your requirement right Your image need to stretch vertically and be in bounds horizontally.

A good solution I could suggest is creating a 9 patch image out of Your drawable and define the area where the image can stretch.
You can use [this](http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files) tutorial for reference.